# Testng scripts throws internal error in eclipse

Tags: testng

package eabm.testcases;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNgscript {

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println("Testing");
}
```

}

error:An internal error occurred during: "Launching TestNgscript".
invalid version "11.0.15.0.1": invalid qualifier "0.1"

Note: working fine if we run it in **mvn test**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9baR.png)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Update the JAVA_VERSION from 11.0.15.0.1 to 11.0.15 in your usr/java/latest/release file.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the test suite name and try to execute it. It worked for me!